# Can't migrate all tables after deleting it manually from database - CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, database-migration, codeigniter-4

Hell i have created two migrations in codeigniter 4 and migrate it.
But after it i deleted it manually from database and now when i run the command

```
php spark migrate
```

this only create table for last migration only in the database

This is my first time using CodeIgniter 4 and didn't use database migrations before. I was doing a manually created database and dealt with but this time i want learn migrations and the project in this way but i got stuck in this problem

**Migration for users:**

```
<?php namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class TblUsers extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
//        $this->db->disableForeignKeyChecks();
        $this->forge->addField([
            'user_id' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],
            'first_name' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'last_name' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'dob' => [
                'type' => 'date'
            ],
            'contact' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'email' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'password' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'role_id' => [
                'type' => 'int'
            ],
            'created_by' => [
                'type' => 'int'
            ],
            'created_at datetime default current_timestamp',
            'updated_by' => [
                'type' => 'int'
            ],
            'updated_at datetime default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp'
        ]);
        $this->forge->addPrimaryKey('user_id');
        $this->forge->addForeignKey('role_id','tbl_user_roles','role_id','cascade', 'SET NULL');
        $this->forge->createTable('tbl_users');
//        $this->db->enableForeignKeyChecks();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function down()
    {
        $this->db->disableForeignKeyChecks();
        $this->forge->dropTable('tbl_users');
        $this->db->enableForeignKeyChecks();
    }
}
```

**Migration for user roles:**

```
<?php namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class TblUserRoles extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([
            'role_id' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],
            'role' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'created_by' => [
                'type' => 'int'
            ],
            'created_at datetime default current_timestamp',
            'updated_by' => [
                'type' => 'int'
            ],
            'updated_at datetime default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp'
        ]);
        $this->forge->addPrimaryKey('role_id');
        $this->forge->createTable('tbl_user_roles');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Directory structor for migrations

[image]

Database table created after migrated

[image]

Migration in CLI

[image]

Comment: The whole point of migrations is to remember what has already been migrated, so it doesn't get executed twice. I assume Codeigniter stores migration info in the `migrations` table in your screenshot. Check the contents of the migration table and delete entries from it if you want to start from scratch.

Comment: yes you are right it store the migration history. I deleted that as well but still couldn't all the table
i do a rollback as well but still it migrate just the role table and not user table

Comment: Would it be possible that somehow the `down` method is invoked during `user` migration? Can you comment out its contents and see if the table is created?

Comment: @El_Vanja nothing i created the whole database again and commented the down method contents as well still no hope. only creates migration table and user_role table

Comment: let me create that it created a row for user table migration in migration table but table is no created

Comment: And you're not getting any errors/warnings/infos anywhere in the logs? Do these migrations run in the correct order? User roles need to be created first in order for the users migration to work (you reference roles when you add the foreign key).

Comment: @El_Vanja i removed everything and create fresh migrations as you told me and remove foreign key as well All good now and create the table. Let me see the documentation for the foreign keys haha

Thank you